# How to merge with jq json arrays elements where elements are objects with nested arrays?

Tags: jq

I have the following json document

```json
[
  {
    "interface": [
      {
        "name": "ethernet-1/1",
        "ifindex": 16382
      },
      {
        "name": "ethernet-1/2",
        "ifindex": 49150
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "interface": [
      {
        "name": "ethernet-1/1",
        "admin-state": "disable"
      },
      {
        "name": "ethernet-1/2",
        "admin-state": "disable"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and I want to merge the elements of this array so that the following output is desired:

```json
[
  {
    "interface": [
      {
        "name": "ethernet-1/1",
        "admin-state": "disable",
        "ifindex": 16382
      },
      {
        "name": "ethernet-1/2",
        "admin-state": "disable",
        "ifindex": 49150
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried a bunch of solutions with `add` and `group_by` but can't quite point my finger at where I am missing some jq knowledge.
Appreciate any suggestions/examples.

The number of top level array elements is not constrained by two, it is just an example.

Comment: By what criteria do you want to match the items? Is it the same position in their respective parent arrays, or is it the value of `.name`, or something else? Also, is `.interface` the only key in the top-level array's items, and can its name vary?

Comment: @pmf .interface key name is static and the only key possible.

I don't (?) need to match/compare elements, as elements in the arrays are unique between themselves.

the `.name` is the common field that group attributes of the interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By what criteria do you want to match the items?

If it is by the same position in their respective parent arrays, you could simply `transpose` the array of arrays, then `add` them up:

```bash
[{interface: map(.interface) | transpose | map(add)}]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/oiDqyAfZxtY)

If it is by the value of `.name`, you could iterate over the items using `reduce`, and collect the matching fields in an object. Use `map(.)` to re-convert it to an array.

```bash
[{interface: (reduce .[].interface[] as $i ({}; .[$i.name] += $i) | map(.))}]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ij5a4YttlHB)

Note: If `.interface` is the only key in the top-level array's items, you could also replace the inner mentions of `.interface` with `.[]`.

For the sample data given, both output:

```json
[
  {
    "interface": [
      {
        "name": "ethernet-1/1",
        "ifindex": 16382,
        "admin-state": "disable"
      },
      {
        "name": "ethernet-1/2",
        "ifindex": 49150,
        "admin-state": "disable"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks, 2nd approach seems to work the best, since it can handle different name keys 

such as when first array elem contains ethernet-1/1, but second only ethernet-1/2